# How to attach Invoice PDF in invoice email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice, pdf, zend-framework

I want to attach invoice pdf to the invoice mail, I followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888153/magento-adding-pdf-invoice-to-invoice-email) and override the email functions.

First Override the app/code/Mage/core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php like,

1. Adding `protected $pdftemplate;`
2. Overriding the `send()` function,

   if($this->pdftemplate){
               $pdftemplate = $this->variable;
           }else{
               $pdftemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
           }
3. Adding attachment function at the end of the class,

   /** Add Attachment**/

   ```
   public function addAttachment(Zend_Pdf $pdf, $filename){
       $file = $pdf->render();
       $this->pdftemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template'); 
       $attachment = $this->pdftemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($file);
       $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
       $attachment->filename = $filename;
   }
   ```

Second I override the app/code/Mage/Sales/Order/Invoice.php, `sendEmail()` function,

```
$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($this));
        $mailer->addAttachment($pdf,'invoice.pdf');
```

But the pdf is not attached. I don't know what to do next. I hope someone will point me the issue.

Thanks!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to try extension first, then if you like you can customize it:
https://marketplace.magento.com/fooman-fooman-emailattachments.html

Feature List

- Automatically attach a copy of Order/Invoice/Shipment/Credit Memo
  pdf documents (with or without comments) to
  Order/Invoice/Shipment/Credit Memo emails
- Automatically attach your
  Terms and Conditions (as html/text file) to
  Order/Invoice/Shipment/Credit Memo emails
- Automatically attach any
  pdf document to Order/Invoice/Shipment/Credit Memo emails (for
  example, your return policy, a coupon or voucher, or your latest
  newsletter)
- Create an Order Confirmation pdf document from the
  Order Overview screen or individual Order View page
- Print Order
  Confirmation pdf documents for multiple orders in bulk from the the
  Order Overview screen
- Developer bonus - if you write your own
  extensions, you can hook into the email sending process into the
  events added by this extension